# Is this a good way to say 'So remember me this way'?

Tags: grammar-choice, meaning, poetry, english-to-latin-translation

> *sic este mei memores hec illac*

I am trying to use it in a poem.  It needs to be 10 syllables and the end has to rhyme with 'attack.'

Is this a good way to say 'So remember me this way'?

Comment: Do you need any particular stress pattern? Rhyming with "attack" also requires a bit of distorted pronunciation, since Classical Latin had no /æ/.

Comment: Iambic pentameter.  How do you pronounce "illac"?

Comment: A little unsolicited advice: This is probably an XY problem. It seems a bit rigid to request Latin verse in iambic-pentameter (though some Church hymns do use such schemes) and especially to require that it rhyme with "attack": don't you have more control over what the previous line is? One does not simply write a line ending in orange and expect the next rhyming line to be easy :)

Comment: If you know IPA, *illāc* is something like /ˈɪlː.ɑːk/. In other words, the first vowel is like in English "ill", the second vowel as in "father". And the stress is on the first syllable.

Comment: @brianpck You're right, I do have complete control over the poem.  I haven't edited the question because I find the near-rhyme of attack and (pronounced) "ill-lock" to be acceptable.  I found what I think is probably a good verbal pronunciation of the word [here](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/how-do-you-pronounce-the/latin-word-2dbc0dad454fea252272d8cf73c0d739a04f8581.html).  I also understand that it will be hard to follow iambic in latin due to the fact that no 2+ syllable words end on a stressed syllable.  In this case, I am not averse to rhyming 'orange' with 'porridge', so to speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have a good translation to offer, so this is not a full answer.
This is more of a commentary that didn't fit in the comment box.
In prose I would translate your phrase as *sic mementote mei*.

Your verse is mostly grammatical, but unfortunately it does not have ten syllables (it has eleven) nor does it rhyme with the English word "attack".
I do not quite understand the function of *h(a?)ec illac*.
The adverb *illac* means "along this road" more concretely than the English "that way" does.
Since you are not describing physical movement, something like *hoc modo* would be better — but on the other hand, *sic* already conveys the "this way".

Classical Latin does not have the vowel sound that appears in "attack".
Instead of /æ/, *illac* has an /a/ (like in "luck").
Rhyming Latin with "attack" is difficult, and I'm not sure if anything would be satisfactory.

About syllables:
In classical Latin *mĕ-ī* has two syllables, one short and one long.
(Synizesis is always possible, though.)
There is no elision in this verse, so all syllables are pronounced.
Classical poetry was based on a length pattern instead of a stress pattern, but of course you don't need to follow classical style in your poem.

Comment: You're saying the 'lac' in illac is pronounced more like 'luck' in English?  Because I pronounce bath and attack with the same sound on the a.

Comment: @Bango Yes, "luck" is a much better (less dialect-dependent) example word. I edited the answer. The second syllable of *illac* is otherwise like *luck*, but the vowel is longer.

Comment: For me "luck" has a /ʌ/; *illac* is like the first vowel in "father".

Comment: @Draconis Oh. I see no difference between the vowels of "luck" and "father", but I'm not native. If you know a good English word with sufficiently uniform pronunciation across dialects, please let me know or edit it in.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The best I can think of is "ah" for consistency. In my dialect of English "luck" is distinct, but "father" and "bother" (and "cot" and "caught") have all merged into a single vowel; someone from England would have all of those separate.

Comment: @Draconis does [this](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/how-do-you-pronounce-the/latin-word-2dbc0dad454fea252272d8cf73c0d739a04f8581.html) sound like the right pronunciation?  If so, I would say that "lock" is the perfect example for my midwestern American dialect.  "EEL-lock".

Comment: @Joonas when you said my verse is mostly grammatical, did you mean it makes sense grammatically, but not practically?  Or more along the lines of, there is a bunch of superfluous grammar which detracts from the meaning?  Or both?

Comment: Thanks for all the commentary.  I've learned from my last 2 questions that I definitely need to be asking around on here before crafting a nightmarish latin verse using google translate and latin verb conj charts.

Comment: @Bango In the Midwest, "EEL-lock" is right. (This is the "cot-caught merger" I mentioned which affects most of America.)

Comment: @Bango The linked pronunciation sounds surprisingly different from how I'd pronounce it. I'm not good at [pronunciation guides through English](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1764/79), but I'd say *illac* is like "ill-ah-k".

Comment: @Bango I forgot to respond to your other comment: The first part *sic este mei memores* is grammatical and makes sense. I would prefer *mementote* to *este memores*, but neither is wrong. I don't see the purpose or meaning of *hec illac*. It seems to be for the purpose of forcing a rhyme, but it doesn't make enough sense (to me at least).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta One more comment then I'll leave it I promise.  You mentioned illac means 'along that road.'  Such as, 'If you keep going you'll see a petrol station illac.'  Assuming hec can translate to something along the lines of 'this', could my original phrase me moderately stretched to give the notion of "So remember me in this way, as traveling along this road" ?  Or just, nah not so much?  Also, does the word 'sic' have multivariate meaning, to convey 'Therefore'/'So' and also 'In this manner' ?  If yes, I see why 'hec illac' is obscure and redundant.

Comment: @Bango Those questions are good ones, but you should ask a new question if you have more. Yes, *sic* already means "in this manner" ([and other similar things](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sic&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)). I would say *illac* means "along that road" as a path of movement, not as location. Therefore it makes sense to walk *illac* but not to see a petrol station *illac*. But my intuition can fail me. As *sic* already contains "this way" and *illac* "along that way/road/...", the pronoun *haec* (in any form) is superfluous.